# Quadratic Field extension which is not simple.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $K$ be a field with characteristic =2 and let $L/K$ be a quadratic field extension which is not of the form $L=K(\sqrt{D})$.
I want to show that there exists an irreducible polynomial in $K[t]$ of the form: $f(t)=t^2-t-D$ such that $L$ is isomorphic to $K(\alpha):=K[t]/(t^2-t-D)$ over $K$.

How do I show it?
If $K$ were $\mathbb{Z}_2$ it would be easy I would choose: $f(t)=t^2-t-1$ which is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ but how to show for any field which has characteristic 2?

Thanks!

Comment: Although there exist quadratic extensions which are not of the form $K(\sqrt{D})$, these extensions are still simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there is a terminological issue here: an extension $L/K$ is called *simple* if there exists an element $\alpha \in L$ such that $L = K(\alpha)$. So the extensions we aim to classify are certainly still simple.

---

That aside, we want to construct an isomorphism $K[t]/(t^2 - t - D) \to L$ for some $D$, so in particular we need to construct a homomorphism $K[t]/(t^2 - t - D) \to L$. This means we're looking for some $D \in K$ such that there exists $\alpha \in L \setminus K$ such that $\alpha^2 - \alpha = D$. In other words, we need to find some $\alpha \in L \setminus K$ such that $\alpha^2 - \alpha \in K$.

Well, let's start by picking any old $m \in L \setminus K$. Since $L/K$ is quadratic, we have $m^2 = a + bm$, where $a,b \in K$. Moreover, we know $m^2 \notin K$ (or else $L = K(m) = K(\sqrt{m^2})$), so $b \neq 0$. Now
$$m^2 - m = a+bm - m = a + (b-1)m,$$
so if we happened to have $b = 1$ we would be done. However, we might have $b \neq 1$ -- in this case, we can modify our choice of $m$ to remedy the situation! I'll leave the rest to you...

Comment: If $b\ne 1$ how can I modify the choice of $m$?

Comment: Ah, I think I can choose $m=1$, in which case: $1^2-1=0=a$. Ok thanks! sleepless nights... :-D

Comment: No! Remember we need $m$ to not be an element of $K$ (why?)

Comment: so I am not sure how to choose $m$ in that case.

Comment: I tried to give a bit of a clue by using the word "modify". You should not completely disregard the initial choice of $m$ (like you did by replacing $m$ with $1$)! Instead, your "new $m$" should be something expressible in terms of "old $m$". So simply try some modifications, plug them in, and see if they work! There aren't really that many things you can possibly try, and one of them is correct. For an even stronger hint: I proved that $b \neq 0$ in my answer, but I never used that fact...

Comment: You mean do I need to just solve the quadratic equation of $m^2-a-bm=0$ with respect to $m$? if not this then I am really clueless here.

Comment: No, at least because that quadratic equation has no variables in it -- $m$ is fixed, and $a$ and $b$ are defined from $m$. Indeed that equation is true by definition of $a$ and $b$.  

What I mean is that you should define $\alpha = \text{something involving } m$, then compute $\alpha^2 - \alpha$ and check if it's an element of $K$. If not, try something else for $\alpha$ and repeat. Eventually you will find an acceptable value of $\alpha$. Of course, how long this takes will depend on how good your "nose-following" intuition is -- with practice, you'll get better at making good guesses.

Comment: FWIW I had never seen this exercise before! I simply followed my nose and "luckily" chose the correct modification right off the bat -- the fact that $b \neq 0$ was a big hint (which I've tried to emphasize).